# Removing a character from a character array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Is there a way to remove characters from a current character array and then save it to a new character array. Following is the code:

```
string s1 = "move";
string s2 = "remove";
char[] c1 = s1.ToCharArray();
char[] c2 = s2.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < s2.Length; i++)
{
  for (int p = 0; p < s1.Length; p++)
  {
    if (c2[i] == c1[p])
    {
      // REMOVE LETTER FROM C2
    }


    // IN THE END I SHOULD JUST HAVE c3 = re (ALL THE MATCHING CHARACTERS M-O-V-E SHOULD BE
       DELETED)
```

Would appreciate your help

Comment: Why not simply use the `string`?

Comment: Perhaps you want `var c3 = s2.Replace(s1, "").ToCharArray();` but if you remove `m`, `o`, `v` and `e` from `remove` then you are left with `r` because you would remove both `e`. Perhaps you should explain what you ultimately want to do.

Comment: Yes, please clarify. Are you simply removing a substring, or are you removing all occurrences of the characters in the remove array, or are you just removing the first occurrence of each characters in the move array?

Comment: I only want one instance of e to be removed. if there were 2 e's in move like movee. Then we would be left with just R

Comment: @Newbiecoder: thank you for the clarification. Please edit your question so that the title more-correctly reflects what you're actually trying to do. And for future reference, you should state your questions by expressing the _end result_ you are trying to achieve, rather than whatever specific implementation you think might achieve it (since after all, you are probably asking the question because your chosen implementation didn't achieve your goal). For example, here a better title for the question might be "Remove a specific word from a string".

Comment: Now, that said: your clarification doesn't really clarify things for me. The word "movee" doesn't appear in the original "remove", so it seems maybe you _don't_ mean you want to remove whole words (i.e. my suggested title change isn't actually correct). Are you saying that you don't care about the order of the letters in s1, but that you do want to use each letter in s1 only once?

Comment: It seems fairly clear to me: He wants to remove the first occurrence (if any) of each of the characters in s1 from s2, and if a character appears multiple times in s1, then it should be removed as many times as it occurs in s1.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly efficient, but it will probably be fast enough for short strings:

```
string s1 = "move";
string s2 = "remove";

foreach (char charToRemove in s1)
{
    int index = s2.IndexOf(charToRemove);

    if (index >= 0)
        s2 = s2.Remove(index, 1);
}

// Result is now in s2.

Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

This avoids converting to a char array.

<strike>However, just to emphasize: This will be VERY slow for large strings.</strike>

[EDIT]

I have done some testing, and it turns out that this code is in fact pretty fast.

Here I'm comparing the code with the optimized code from another answer. However, note that we're not comparing entirely fairly, since the code here correctly implements the OP's requirement while the other code doesn't. However, it does demonstrate that the use of HashSet doesn't help as much as one might think.

I tested this code on a release build, not run inside a debugger (if you run it in a debugger, it does a debug build not a release build which will give incorrect timings).

This test uses target strings of length 1024 and chars to remove == `"SKFPBPENAALDKOWJKFPOSKLW"`.

My results, where `test1()` is the incorrect but supposedly optimized solution from another answer, and `test2()` is my unoptimized but correct solution:

```
test1() took 00:00:00.2891665
test2() took 00:00:00.1004743

test1() took 00:00:00.2720192
test2() took 00:00:00.0993898

test1() took 00:00:00.2753971
test2() took 00:00:00.0997268

test1() took 00:00:00.2754325
test2() took 00:00:00.1026486

test1() took 00:00:00.2785548
test2() took 00:00:00.1039417

test1() took 00:00:00.2818029
test2() took 00:00:00.1029695

test1() took 00:00:00.2727377
test2() took 00:00:00.0995654

test1() took 00:00:00.2711982
test2() took 00:00:00.1009849
```

As you can see, `test2()` consistently outperforms `test1()`. This remains true even if the strings are increased to length 8192.

The test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            string text = randomString(8192, 27367);
            string charsToRemove = "SKFPBPENAALDKOWJKFPOSKLW";

            int dummyLength = 0;

            int iters = 10000;

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 8; ++trial)
            {
                sw.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
                    dummyLength += test1(text, charsToRemove).Length;

                Console.WriteLine("test1() took " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
                    dummyLength += test2(text, charsToRemove).Length;

                Console.WriteLine("test2() took " + sw.Elapsed);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private static string randomString(int length, int seed)
        {
            var rng = new Random(seed);
            var sb = new StringBuilder(length);

            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
                sb.Append((char) rng.Next(65, 65 + 26*2));

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private static string test1(string text, string charsToRemove)
        {
            HashSet<char> excludeCharacters = new HashSet<char>(charsToRemove);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char ch in text)
            {
                if (!excludeCharacters.Contains(ch))
                {
                    sb.Append(ch);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private static string test2(string text, string charsToRemove)
        {
            foreach (char charToRemove in charsToRemove)
            {
                int index = text.IndexOf(charToRemove);

                if (index >= 0)
                    text = text.Remove(index, 1);
            }

            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT 2]

Here's a much more optimized solution:

```
public static string RemoveChars(string text, string charsToRemove)
{
    char[] result = new char[text.Length];
    char[] targets = charsToRemove.ToCharArray();
    int n = 0;
    int m = targets.Length;

    foreach (char ch in text)
    {
        if (m == 0)
        {
            result[n++] = ch;
        }
        else
        {
            int index = findFirst(targets, ch, m);

            if (index < 0)
            {
                result[n++] = ch;
            }
            else
            {
                if (m > 1)
                {
                    --m;
                    targets[index] = targets[m];
                }
                else
                {
                    m = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new string(result, 0, n);
}

private static int findFirst(char[] chars, char target, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (chars[i] == target)
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

Plugging that into my test program above shows that it runs around 3 times faster than `test2()`.

Comment: It is very slow and this specific result can be done in O(N) instead of O(N^2) as here. So, no...this doesn't seem like a good answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It's a perfectly good answer if the strings are small though (and is likely to be faster than more complex implementations). It very much depends on the requirements. It also has the advantage that it actually implements the OP's requirements.

Comment: Actually, the OP hasn't clarified anything in a useful way, as his new explanation isn't terribly clear. That said, even if we assume that you've succeeded in addressing his requirements, this is still not an efficient solution. Even if O(N^2) is acceptable, needlessly allocating new objects is not. Use StringBuilder for s2 instead of generating a new string instance every time you want to remove a character.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I maintain that it is efficient enough. See my test timings.

Comment: suit yourself. I see the update...I see problems with the way you're doing the testing (especially the likelihood of ignoring GC overhead in your approach), but frankly I think we've had enough back and forth at this point. The OP still hasn't truly clarified the goal, and surely he is capable of selecting from the many options offered at this point. Only real-world testing will reveal whether any given solution is deficient performance-wise anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a third array, `c3`, where you will add characters from `c2` that are not to be removed.

You may also use `Replace`.

```
string s3 = s2.Replace(s1,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

The original O(N^2) approach is wasteful. And I don't see how the other two answers actually perform the work you seem to be trying to accomplish. I hope this example, which has O(N) performance, works better for you:

```
string s1 = "move";
string s2 = "remove";
HashSet<char> excludeCharacters = new HashSet<char>(s1);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Copy every character from the original string, except those to be excluded
foreach (char ch in s2)
{
    if (!excludeCharacters.Contains(ch))
    {
        sb.Append(ch);
    }
}

return sb.ToString();
```

Granted, for short strings the performance isn't likely to matter. But IMHO this is also easier to comprehend than the alternatives.

EDIT:

It is still not entirely clear to me what the OP is trying to do here. The most obvious task would be to remove whole words, but neither of his descriptions seem to say that's what he really wants. So, on the assumption that the above is not addressing his needs, but that he also does not want to remove whole words, here are a couple of other options...

1) O(N), the best approach for strings of non-trivial length, but is somewhat more complicated:

```
string s1 = "move";
string s2 = "remove";
Dictionary<char, int> excludeCharacters = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach (char ch in s1)
{
    int count;

    excludeCharacters.TryGetValue(ch, out count);
    excludeCharacters[ch] = ++count;
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char ch in s2)
{
    int count;

    if (!excludeCharacters.TryGetValue(ch, out count) || count == 0)
    {
        sb.Append(ch);
    }
    else
    {
        excludeCharacters[ch] = --count;
    }
}

return sb.ToString();
```

2) An O(N^2) implementation which at least minimizes other unnecessary inefficiencies and which would suffice if all the inputs are relatively short:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s2);

foreach (char ch in s1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
    {
        if (sb[i] == ch)
        {
            sb.Remove(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This won't take the order of characters in consideration, does it?

Comment: Which order? The characters in the new string will be in the same order seen in the original s2 string. The order of the characters in the s1 string don't matter. In the OP's example each is simply being removed from the original string, without regard for order, so this example also does not consider the order of characters in s1.

Comment: Thing is, this returns "r" for the OP's problem, but he states that he wants "re" to be returned. (Also, it'd be better writing that as `string result = new string(s2.Except(s1).ToArray());` anyway.)

Comment: You are correct to point out that the OP's comment does not match the code he posted. In programming, code rules so that's what I followed. The OP can follow up with a clarification if he wants to make his code and comment match. :)

Comment: Well, one might say that he's posting the question because his code DOESN'T work how he wants it to. ;)

Comment: One could say that. Or one could say that he's posting the question because he doesn't know what goes in place of his comment "// REMOVE LETTER FROM C2". There are a lot of things one could say. If and when the OP clarifies, then we'll know what one _should_ say. I readily agree that your interpretation could be correct, but I don't find it more or less compelling than my own.

Comment: Indeed, but see my second comment: Your code is basically replicating the built-in Linq `Except()` method, so it's probably better to use that instead.

Comment: I prefer to avoid the extra buffer allocation, but I certainly don't object if someone else would rather use the LINQ approach. You're well within your rights to propose that, even in an addendum to a previous-posted comment. :)

Comment: Now that the OP has updated his post, it's clear that this doesn't answer his requirement. You might also want to fix the code so that it compiles in any case - you can't do `new HashSet(s1)` - it won't compile.